# How do I configure the type provided as the Service attribute value in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, c#-4.0

I have the following configured in my `<system.serviceModel>` tag of my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings/>
  <client/>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceTypeBehaviors">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceTypeBehaviors" name="AcpService.MainFrameData">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AcpService.IMainFrameService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The XML of my service is this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="AcpService.MainFrameData" CodeBehind="MainFrameWoData.svc.cs" %>
```

My application is running in the **Default Web Site**'s Application Pool with **Enable 32-Bit Applications** set to **True** (because the service uses some old data accessing libraries).

When I run it, I get this error:

### Server Error in '/mainframe' Application.

**The type 'AcpService.MainFrameData', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.**

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'AcpService.MainFrameData', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

I almost modified my `<serviceHostingEnvironment>` tag to include the `<serviceActions>` parameters, but I don't really understand how to do that.

This is how far I got:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
      relativeAddress="~/mainframe/MainFrameWoData.svc"
      service="AcpService.MainFrameData" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly, and I have no idea what to insert for the **service=** parameter. The  info on MSDN seems useless.

This project originally had a different name, but I am having to add features to the service. I do not want to edit the active service, because doing so would mean all the employees trying to access the data on our internal network would be getting that error right now, so the service was copied to a new project, and it is being published to a new location on our server. My best guess is there is something in the `web.config` file (or ???) that does not match up to something the project itself.

Could someone give me some help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my project wanted **MainFrameService** instead of **MainFrameData**.

I started to delete this post, but... who knows? Perhaps someone else can get some use out of it.